# Chart.js: Labels above bars in horizontal bar chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I building an Angular app using `ng2-charts` (Chart.js) where I can switch between months to see the categories of my expenses as a horizontal bar.

**I want it to look like this:**

[image: Example]

### **What I have now is this:**

======================= **SCREENSHOT 1** =======================

[image: Few categories]

======================= **SCREENSHOT 2** =======================

[image: More categories]

======================= **SCREENSHOT 3** =======================

[image: Many categories]

As you can see each page looks different because the amount of categories is not known beforehand. This is computed and sent to me by the backend. So my question is: **how do I increase the spacing between the bars while keeping the thickness of the bars identical, so that I can always apply the same offset to the labels and render them above the bar?**

I've tried playing around with `barThickness`, `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage`, but didn't manage to achieve the desired reult.

Here are my bar-chart options and the plugin that I wrote to add the label:

```
  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
        ticks: { stepSize: 1 }, // bar fills canvas
      },
      y: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  };

  public moveLabelTopPlugin: Plugin = {
    id: 'moveLabelTopPlugin',
    afterDatasetDraw(chart) {
      const {
        ctx,
        data,
        chartArea: { left },
        scales: { x, y },
      } = chart;

      ctx.save();

      data.datasets[0].data.forEach((dataPoint, index) => {
        ctx.font = 'bolder 16px sans-serif';

        ctx.fillText(
          (data.labels && data.labels[index]) as string,
          0,
          y.getPixelForValue(index)
        );
      });
    },
  };
```

**The template (HTML)**

```
<canvas #canvas
        baseChart
        [data]="data"
        [plugins]="[moveLabelTopPlugin]"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        type="bar"
        (chartClick)="onClick($event, data)">
</canvas>
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look :)